# Azure: Do not deploy a role by configuration

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-configuration

We have written a high scalable Cloudservice for MS Azure with two roles: "WebsiteRole" and "WebsiteWorkerRole". For better performance we deploy this Cloudservice in multiple regions (2x US, 2x EU, 1x JP). We have different configuration files for each region (EuWestProductive.azurePubxml, ServiceConfiguration.CloudEuWest.cscfg, Web.ReleaseEuWest.config).

Now the Problem: In each Region we have running the "WebsiteRole" and "WebsiteWorkerRole". But the "WebsiteWorkerRole" has only very small tasks, so that one extra small instance in one region is more than enough.

We tried to set the Role instance count to zero (ServiceConfiguration.CloudEuWest.cscfg). But this is not allowed:
[Azure Feedback: Allow a Role instance count of 0](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role/suggestions/743252-allow-a-role-instance-count-of-0)

Is there an other way to remove a role when deploy the Cloudservice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as you've discovered, a cloud service does not allow for scale to zero. You have to effectively remove the deployment. To have the minimum change to what you already have in place you could separate the two roles into two different deployments. Then have an Azure Automation Script, or set of scripts run elsewhere, that handles deploying the worker role when needed and decommissioning when it's not needed.

Depending on the type of workload that worker is doing you could also look at taking another route of using something like Azure Automation to perform the work. This is especially true if it's a small amount of processing that occurs only a few times a day. You're charged by the minute for the automation script, so just make sure it's going to run less than the actual current instance does.

It really boils down to what that worker is doing, how much processing it really needs to do, how much resources it needs and how often it needs to be running. There are a lot of options, such as Azure Automation, another thread on the web role, a separate cloud service deployment, etc. Each with their own pros and cons. One option might even to look at the new Azure Functions they just announced (in preview and charged by the execution).

The short answer is separate the worker from the WebSiteRole deployment, then decide the best hosting mechanism for that worker role making sure that the option includes the ability to only run when you need it to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @MikeWo, your idea to separate the deployments was great!
I have verified this with an small example project and it works just fine. Now it is also possible to change the VM size and other configurations per region.

[image: Example project]

(Comments do not allow images)

Comment: Technically, yes, but for some settings that are in the ServiceDefinition file, such as the VM Size, you have to do some work to get that to happen before you do the build and deploy since that file is packaged up with the code. There are numerous ways to accomplish that, such as custom build steps, separate Cloud Project projects in VS like what you've done above, etc. Any configuration in the service configuration is easily handled at deployment time.